# How to change the label font color of a caption of one table only?

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting

I'm using the `xcolor` package, and for changing the color of any selected of any figure or table in the document I use.

`\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=blue}}`

but this did not work with the table!

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Here is a sample of the code of the table where the caption color needed to be changed (caption:label and description).

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=blue}}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Caption of the table \label{table:test table}}
\end{table}
\clearcaptionsetup{table}
```

Comment: Remove `[figure]`, so the setting is done for all captions.

Comment: Thanks egreg, I have tried it with table and removed [Table] and didn't work!

Answer (score 5):

From what I can understand, you want figure captions to be blue, but table captions generally black, with an occasional table caption blue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=blue}}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want *all* captions to be blue, use

```
\captionsetup{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=blue}}
```

However, note that pure colors should not be generally used. Possibly better is doing `\colorlet{mildblue}{blue!80!green}` and changing all `blue` into `mildblue`.

<sub>**Production note.** The picture was produced with     `\setcounter{totalnumber}{100}` so LaTeX allows more than three floats in a page.</sub>

Comment: Thanks egreg, I have used your code sample and it works but with other document class (rather than article) it is not work with the journal template that I am working on! An occasional Table caption did not change its color in that class of document!

Comment: @mhdella Without a full example with the class you use it's not easy to help more.

Comment: documentclass{cta-author} this is the class I am using for Elsevier journal and I don't know how to upload it here!

Comment: @mhdella If you use a class for a journal submission, why are you changing their setup?

Comment: Good question, for the second revision draft... I have to make some parts with another color to show the reviewers that the corrections have taken a place.

Comment: @mhdella Sorry, but, again, without a minimal example and a pointer to where the class can be examined, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Here is the link of a compressed zip folder that has the template file of the document class which its name is: cta-author.cls. I hope you can use it in your code example and find a way to change the color of an occasional table caption as you did with article class document.   http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip