# Change color of label based on what Environment I'm currently in

Tags: color, captions, environments, environment-variables

Here's my current preamble.tex

```latex
\documentclass{report}

% basics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={black},
  citecolor={black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

% theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em, innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=6pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\makeatletter

\@ifclasswith{report}{nocolor}{
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, mdframed={ nobreak } ]{thmgreenbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, mdframed={ nobreak } ]{thmredbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont]{thmbluebox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont]{thmblueline}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, numbered=no, mdframed={ rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false, }, qed=\qedsymbol ]{thmproofbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, numbered=no, mdframed={ nobreak, rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false } ]{thmexplanationbox}
  \AtEndEnvironment{eg}{\null\hfill$\diamond$}%
}{
  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{ForestGreen!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=ForestGreen, backgroundcolor=ForestGreen!5,
  }
  ]{thmgreenbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{NavyBlue!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!5,
  }
  ]{thmbluebox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{NavyBlue!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue
  }
  ]{thmblueline}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{RawSienna!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=RawSienna, backgroundcolor=RawSienna!5,
  }
  ]{thmredbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{RawSienna!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  numbered=no,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=RawSienna, backgroundcolor=RawSienna!1,
  },
  qed=\color{RawSienna!70!black}\qedsymbol
  ]{thmproofbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{NavyBlue!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  numbered=no,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!1,
  },
  ]{thmexplanationbox}
}

\@ifclasswith{report}{nocolor}{
  \declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
  \declaretheorem[style=thmexplanationbox, name=Proof]{explanation}
  \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}
}{
  \declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
  \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}

  \declaretheorem[style=thmexplanationbox, name=Proof]{tmpexplanation}
  \newenvironment{explanation}[1][]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{tmpexplanation}}{\end{tmpexplanation}}
}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem[style=thmgreenbox, name=Definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Proposition]{prop}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Lemma]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, numbered=no, name=Corollary]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Remark]{remark}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Example]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Solution]{solution}

\newtheorem{exc}{Exercise}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem*{previouslyseen}{As previously seen}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{observe}{Observe}
\newtheorem*{property}{Property}
\newtheorem*{intuition}{Intuition}

\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}
    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the label color to change to the color of the border from the environment? In this example, how would I change the label color to be green like the definition environment?

Comment: Please make your example complete, by adding missing `\documentclass` line and `document` environment.

Comment: `\AtBeinEnvironment{<envname>}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=<color>}}` may work.

Comment: Please always provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). You provided us a lot of info that are not connected with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final answer. Thanks a ton to @FHZ

This answer uses

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{<envname>}{
  \captionsetup{...}
}
```

to define how all captions will be presented inside each environment.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

% basics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={black},
  citecolor={black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em, innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=6pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\colorlet{thmgreencolor}{ForestGreen!70!black}
\colorlet{thmredcolor}{RawSienna!70!black}
\colorlet{thmbluecolor}{NavyBlue!70!black}
\colorlet{thmblueline}{NavyBlue!70!black}
\colorlet{thmproofbox}{RawSienna!70!black}
\colorlet{thmexplanationbox}{NavyBlue!70!black}

\makeatletter

\@ifclasswith{report}{nocolor}{
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, mdframed={ nobreak } ]{thmgreenbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, mdframed={ nobreak } ]{thmredbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont]{thmbluebox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont]{thmblueline}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, numbered=no, mdframed={ rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false, }, qed=\qedsymbol ]{thmproofbox}
  \declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bfseries\sffamily, bodyfont=\normalfont, numbered=no, mdframed={ nobreak, rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false } ]{thmexplanationbox}
  \AtEndEnvironment{eg}{\null\hfill$\diamond$}%
}{
  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmgreencolor}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=ForestGreen, backgroundcolor=ForestGreen!5,
  }
  ]{thmgreenbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmredcolor}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=RawSienna, backgroundcolor=RawSienna!5,
  }
  ]{thmredbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmbluecolor}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!5,
  }
  ]{thmbluebox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmblueline}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue
  }
  ]{thmblueline}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmproofbox}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  numbered=no,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=RawSienna, backgroundcolor=RawSienna!1,
  },
  qed=\color{RawSienna!70!black}\qedsymbol
  ]{thmproofbox}

  \declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{thmexplanationbox}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  numbered=no,
  mdframed={
    linewidth=2pt,
    rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
    linecolor=NavyBlue, backgroundcolor=NavyBlue!1,
  },
  ]
  {thmexplanationbox}
}

\@ifclasswith{report}{nocolor}{
  \declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
  \declaretheorem[style=thmexplanationbox, name=Proof]{explanation}
  \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}
}{
  \declaretheorem[style=thmproofbox, name=Proof]{replacementproof}
  \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{replacementproof}}{\end{replacementproof}}

  \declaretheorem[style=thmexplanationbox, name=Proof]{tmpexplanation}
  \newenvironment{explanation}[1][]{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{tmpexplanation}}{\end{tmpexplanation}}
}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem[style=thmgreenbox, name=Definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Proposition]{prop}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Lemma]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, numbered=no, name=Corollary]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Remark]{remark}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Example]{example}
\declaretheorem[style=thmblueline, numbered=no, name=Solution]{solution}

\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmgreencolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{prop}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmredcolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmredcolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lemma}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmredcolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{corollary}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmredcolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{remark}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmbluecolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmbluecolor}}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{
  \captionsetup{labelfont={color=thmbluecolor}}
}

\newtheorem{exc}{Exercise}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem*{previouslyseen}{As previously seen}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem*{observe}{Observe}
\newtheorem*{property}{Property}
\newtheorem*{intuition}{Intuition}

\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}[Some Definition]
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{definition}

  \newpage

  \begin{prop}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{prop}

  \begin{theorem}[Some Theorem]
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{lemma}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{lemma}

  \begin{corollary}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{corollary}

  \newpage

  \begin{remark}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{remark}

  \begin{example}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{example}

  \begin{solution}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[H]
      \label{tbl:degrees_into_radians}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Some Cool Label}
    \end{table}
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I must say, the final result of your style is really beautiful.

Comment: I added a brief explanation of the core concept you used in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412476/how-to-change-the-label-font-color-of-a-caption-of-one-table-only), a possible solution is presented in the following MWE based on [caption](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=green!50!black},font={color=green}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=red},font={color=red!50}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Personal opinion*: I always see `green` as too bright and normally difficult to look at, I *prefer* `green!50!black`.

---

#### Edit -- Improved answer

Let's quote [caption](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf)'s manual page 4.

> It’s good to know that \captionsetup has an effect on the current
> environment only. So if you want to change settings for the current
> figure or table only, just place the \captionsetup command inside the
> figure or table right before the \caption command.

So the idea is to define a specific `\captionsetup` inside each `\newenvironment`. In the MWE those `\newenvironment` are `mySpecialEnvironment`.

I also used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161754/how-can-i-adjust-the-number-of-figures-latex-will-display-on-a-page) to keep all captions on the same page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=green!50!black},font={color=green}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=red},font={color=red!50}}

\newenvironment{mySpecialEnvironment}
  {\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=purple!75!black},font={color=purple}}
  \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=orange!75!black},font={color=orange}}
  }
  {}

\setcounter{topnumber}{8}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{8}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{mySpecialEnvironment}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{A table}
  \end{table}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{mySpecialEnvironment}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{mySpecialEnvironment}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{A table}
  \end{table}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{mySpecialEnvironment}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: Please, notice there might be other answers using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` like your `\declaretheorem`s, but here I didn't look for these options.

Comment: Thanks! But, how would I add it to the environment? For example, I would like to make all of the captions green when inside the definition environment, but all the captions red when the theorem environment.

Comment: I need to investigate further. Despite my answer does answers the basic question, it does not answer your real question. It is something like this: "How do I want to define an environment that defines the color of each caption inside it but not outside it".

Comment: @SingularisArt, please, check if the edit improved answer satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!